# PHP mysql_query SELECT * FROM syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I have crated a table that shows the results from a mysql database, there is also a  search box that users can use to filter the results. The search box creates a variable called $query.
However, results I do not want to be displayed contain the letter "y" in a column called "private" in the database. 
I know how to display the search results, and hide the private ones separately, however I cannot get both functions to work at the same time.
The PHP I have for this at the moment is:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE  private != 'y' (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`tags` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`user` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

However this reterns:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`title` LIKE '%%') OR (`tags` LIKE '%%') OR (`user` LIKE '%%') ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1
```

I am completely stumped as I cannot see how to fix this, I know this is probably a really simple problem but your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You forgot an AND before (title (and the ( ) enclosing the ORs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an AND, and probably a few ():

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE
  private != 'y' AND (
    (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
    (tags LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
    (user LIKE '%".$query."%')
  )
  ORDER BY id DESC"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it straight away!

Answer (score 0):

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE private <> 'y' and (title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (tags LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (user LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your conditions inside  `()` to works like you want
try this:

```
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file 
                                WHERE  private != 'y' AND (
                                (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
                                (`tags` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
                                (`user` LIKE '%".$query."%')
                                ) ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need an AND:

```
WHERE private != 'y' AND ((title LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (tags LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (user LIKE '%".$query."%'))
```